# Wait for Completion Handler to Finish

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nsopenpanel

I have code after a completion handler that is dependent on the completion of the completion handler.

```
 openFilePanel.beginWithCompletionHandler({ (result) -> Void in

        if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton{

            self.fileURL = openFilePanel.URL
            self.window.title = self.fileManager.displayNameAtPath(self.fileURL!.absoluteString!)
            self.pathControl.URL = self.fileURL
            self.webView.mainFrameURL = self.fileURL!.absoluteString!



            self.fileDes = open("\(self.fileURL!.path!)", O_RDONLY)
            println("File Des:\(self.fileDes)")


        }

        })

   println("File Desc:\(self.fileDes)")
```

The final println statement in the code above executes before the user has a chance to choose a file and click OK in the NSOpenPanel. 
Is there a way to delay further code from running until the Ok button has actually been selected?

Comment: What about that `println` move into completion block?

Comment: Agreed. And if your goal is to pass back the file information to some calling routine, then employ a completionHandler pattern if your own code, too.

Answer (score 1):

one solution is to use semaphores:

```
let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)   // 1-

openFilePanel.beginWithCompletionHandler({ (result) -> Void in

    if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton{

        self.fileURL = openFilePanel.URL
        self.window.title = self.fileManager.displayNameAtPath(self.fileURL!.absoluteString!)
        self.pathControl.URL = self.fileURL
        self.webView.mainFrameURL = self.fileURL!.absoluteString!



        self.fileDes = open("\(self.fileURL!.path!)", O_RDONLY)
        println("File Des:\(self.fileDes)")
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)    // 2- 

    }

    })



   dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)  // 3-
   println("File Desc:\(self.fileDes)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole point of the completion handler is to execute code once the user has chosen either Ok or Cancel.

So the only way to delay the final println() statement until the user has made its choice is to call it from the completion handler.

If you have more than a println statement to execute though, put them in a function and call that function from the completion handler.